# Get reference to clicked item in view

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I've recently been learning the MVVM pattern in WPF and just started making my first proper, rather big application. So far it's all smooth sailing, and I'm liking what I'm seeing a lot. However I recently met something of a stumbling block.

The application is built with a main `TabControl`, each `TabItem` containing a pretty big details view.

```
TabControl inside main View, ItemsSource bound to MainViewModel.OpenTabs
 TabItem with data specific View+ViewModel
 TabItem with data specific View+ViewModel
 TabItem with data specific View+ViewModel
 etc...
```

The `OpenTabs` collection is an `ObservableCollection<BaseViewModel>` on `MainViewModel`, and the `TabControl`'s `SelectedItem` is bound to `MainViewModel.ActiveTab`.

So far so good! However, what I'm not sure I'm getting is how to handle closing of tabs while at the same time following MVVM. If I wasn't trying to be strict with the MVVM (in order to learn it properly), I'd just bind a `MouseDown`-event on the `TabItem`-headers and thus get a reference to the clicked item in that event, removing it from the `OpenTabs` collection in that way. But - unless I'm mistaken - the interaction logic shouldn't need references to actual UI items in order to be effective and proper MVVM.

So, how do I handle this MVVM style? Do I use a command that sends a specific parameter with it to my `MainViewModel`? It seems like the preferred implementation of `ICommand` in MVVM doesn't take object parameters (looking at MVVM Light as well as some other tutorials).

Should I just create a `CloseTab(int id)` public method on my `MainViewModel` and call that from the view codebehind after catching the `Click` on my `TabItem` close button? This seems like MVVM-cheating. :)

Also a final note - this should work even if I click close on a `TabItem` that isn't the currently active one. Otherwise it wouldn't be hard to setup with `OpenTabs.Remove(ActiveTab)`.

Thanks for any help! I'd also appreciate any links to recommended reading/watching regarding these problems.

**Solution:** It seems the best way is to use a command that can accept command parameters. I used the RelayCommand from MVVM Light framework:

In MainViewModel:

```
CloseTabCommand = new RelayCommand<BaseViewModel>((vm) =>
{
    OpenTabs.Remove(vm);
});
```

In XAML:

```
<Button
Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource MainViewModel}, Path=CloseTabCommand}"
CommandParameter="{Binding}">
```

Note: Your binding paths may of course vary depending on how your Views and ViewModels are set up.

Comment: It would depend on what MVVM framework you are using really. The general idea is that the VM has an `ICommand` that causes all bound views to "go away", but there are lots of options there. For example, the command could cause an event to be raised; the views could subscribe to that event and remove themselves from the logical tree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best and the right way is to create the command. In different frameworks `ICommand` usually has two implementation, with the parameter and without one (as often you do not need it).

MVVM light has two `ICommand` implementation as well: [`RelayCommand`](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/d60b086fe424#GalaSoft.MvvmLight/GalaSoft.MvvmLight%20%28NET35%29/Command/RelayCommand.cs) and [`RelayCommand<T>`](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/d60b086fe424#GalaSoft.MvvmLight/GalaSoft.MvvmLight%20%28NET35%29/Command/RelayCommandGeneric.cs)

Comment: Ahhh - there we have it. This makes it all a lot easier. My bad for not noticing the generic command parameter version of RelayCommand.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest creating your own `DelegateCommand` implementation, a good example on how to this can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921126%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx) or [here](http://kentb.blogspot.com/2009/04/mvvm-infrastructure-delegatecommand.html). Or use the Prism [variant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg431410%28v=pandp.39%29.aspx), you can download it [here](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/).

With a DelegateCommand you can pass arguments down to your ViewModel.

Comment: Thank you for your response. It seems this is the preferred way, and I simply didn't notice the RelayCommand<T> in my framework.